# JQuery - Change the value of a checkbox by clicking on it

Tags: jquery

I am working on a little calculator by using jquery. It works fine so far, but not with checkboxes. The checkbox have a default value="200" but it should only sum if the checkbox is checked.

I hope you understand me right!
Heres my code:

```
<div>
<label for="horse">Horse</label>
<select id="horse" class="" name="horse" title="" size="1">
<option value="0 ">choose</option>
<option value="100">Horse 1 (+100 EUR)</option>
<option value="200">Horse 2 (+200 EUR)</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<label for="saddle">Saddle</label>
<select id="saddle" class="" name="sattel" title="" size="1">
<option value="0 ">choose</option>
<option value="400.20">Saddle 1 (+400,20 EUR )</option>
<option value="500.57">Saddle 2 (+500,57 EUR)</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>
<input type="hidden" alt="ghost" value="" name="pet">
<input id="pet" class="label_left" type="checkbox" name="haustier" title="" value="200">
<label for="pet">Pet?</label>
</div>
<div class="total"></div>
```

and my jquery:

```
$(function() {
$('#horse').change(endergebnis);
$('#saddle').change(endergebnis);
$("#pet").change(function () {
    if ($('#pet:checked').val('') ) {
        $('#pet').val();
    } else {
        $('#pet').val('0');
    }

});
});
function endergebnis(){
var horse = $('#horse').val();
var saddle = $('#saddle').val();
var pet = $('#pet').val();

var total =
    Number(horse) + 
    Number(saddle) +
    Number(pet)

$('.total').html(total + " EUR");
};
```

my jsfidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/tobisagt/g2fsQ/372/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the value of the checkbox I'm just using the clicked attribute as a boolean and setting it to 200 if it's checked, this could of course be extracted into a variable if you needed.

```
$(function () {
    $('#horse').change(endergebnis);
    $('#saddle').change(endergebnis);
    $("#pet").change(endergebnis);
});

function endergebnis() {
    var horse = +$('#horse').val();
    var saddle = +$('#saddle').val();
    var pet = ($('#pet').attr('checked')) ? 200 : false;
    if (pet) {
        var total = (horse + saddle + pet).toFixed(2);
        $('.total').html(total + " EUR");
    } else {
        $('.total').html("");
    }
}
```

also notice that rather than using `Number(var)` I am using the shorthand integer conversion of prepending an element selection with a `+`.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2fsQ/377/)

EDIT - It seems that I misinterpreted the OP slightly, see updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2fsQ/380/) where checking the pet checkbox adds 200 to the value, unchecking it removes 200 from the value, the new code is:

```
function endergebnis() {
    var horse = +$('#horse').val();
    var saddle = +$('#saddle').val();
    var pet = ($('#pet').attr('checked')) ? +$('#pet').val() : 0;
    var total = (horse + saddle + pet).toFixed(2);
    $('#total').html(total + " EUR");
}
```

Comment: That's by design, I interpreted where OP says `but it should only sum if the checkbox is checked.` as unless the checkbox is checked, do nothing. If that's not the case [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2fsQ/379/) should be right

Comment: Your second fiddle is right!! Next time i will express myself better! Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help, I think I may have been inadvertently making this more complex than it needed to be. Remember to upvote useful answers as well :)

Comment: @MattFletcher also deserves an upvote for his inputs, when you have the rep.

Comment: Final version of this answer is definitely the most elegant of them all, upvoted!

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted your answer as you got the crux of the issue first time and came up with a nice solution, syntactically the above works pretty well though.

Comment: Your solution dont work with jQuery 1.9.1 see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tobisagt/g2fsQ/382/

It shows only "0".

Comment: Sorry, change `attr('checked')` for `prop('checked')` and it should work, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2fsQ/383/)

Comment: Not a problem, thank you for letting me know about the issue, it should help other SO users as well.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
$(function() {
    $('#horse').change(endergebnis);
    $('#saddle').change(endergebnis);

    $("#pet").data('val', '0');

    $("#pet").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).data('val', $(this).val());
        } else {
            $(this).data('val', '0');
        }
        endergebnis();
    });
});
function endergebnis(){
    var horse = $('#horse').val();
    var saddle = $('#saddle').val();
    var pet = $("#pet").data('val');

    var total =
        Number(horse) + 
        Number(saddle) +
        Number(pet)

    $('.total').html(total + " EUR");
};
```

I moved the value to the data object so that you don't have to manually write the '200' into the javascript..

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4LsA8/3/

Comment: After about a million billion answer edits, I think the above is probably the simplest way of doing it!

Comment: this isn't working fine yet, when you change first drop down for the first time it gives added value oo check box even if it's not checked.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function() {
        $('#horse').change(endergebnis);
        $('#saddle').change(endergebnis);
        //$("#pet").click(function () {
        $('#pet').mousedown(function() {
            if($('#pet').is(":checked")){
                $('#pet').val('0');
            } else {
                $('#pet').val('200');
            }
            endergebnis();
        });
    });
    function endergebnis(){
        var horse = $('#horse').val();
        var saddle = $('#saddle').val();
        var pet = $('#pet').val();

        var total =
            Number(horse) + 
            Number(saddle) +
            Number(pet)

        $('.total').html(total + " EUR");
    };
```

live fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2fsQ/375/)

Answer (score 0):

try this: (I have moved the check on the checkbox inside the calculation. if it is not checked i set the value to 0!)

```
function endergebnis(){
  var horse = $('#horse').val();
  var saddle = $('#saddle').val();
  var pet = $('#pet').val();
 if (!$('#edit-checkbox-id').is(':checked')) {
    pet = 0;
 };


  var total = Number(horse) + Number(saddle) + Number(pet);

  $('.total').html(total + " EUR");
};
```